# SQL - UPSERT LOOP through SELECT's resultset

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following query that is returning two columns of data `UserID` & `ServiceID` from tables `a` & `b`

```
SELECT a.UserID, b.ServiceID FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b
ON b.EventID = a.EventID
WHERE a.EventID = 1892286
AND a.Attendance IN (1,2)
```

The above query returns the following data set:

```
UserID  ServiceID
1       33
2       44
3       55
```

I need to UPSERT into table `c` the following way:
If `UserID` & `ServiceID` exist in table `c` then take current value of column `Scheduled` from table `c` and add `1`

If `UserID` & `ServiceID` do NOT exist in table `c` then insert record into table `c` with selected `UserID` and `ServiceID` from the above select statement and add `1` into the `Scheduled` column.

My question is how to do this for every single row that is returned by my select statement to ensure all results are UPSERTED into table `c`

I'm looking through looping case or if-else statements as possible solutions but any input is appreciated.

My attempt at the above:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT sa.UserID as S_UserID, ce.ServiceID as S_ServiceID FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b
ON b.EventID = a.EventID
WHERE a.EventID = 1892286
AND a.Attendance IN (1,2))
UPDATE TableC c
SET
UserID = S_UserID
ServiceID = S_ServiceID
Scheduled = Scheduled + 1
WHERE UserID = S_UserID
AND ServiceID = S_ServiceID
ELSE
INSERT INTO TableC
(UserID,ServiceID,Scheduled)
VALUES
(S_UserID,S_ServiceID,1)
END
```

Comment: No alias defined for sa or ce.  None of that is valid syntax.

Comment: @Paparazzi yes, i had modified a bit my original code to generalize it for stackoverflow, i missed those aliases. Thanks everyone for the examples i'm going to try all of them to see which works best for my implementation and accept accordingly.

Comment: Then fix the question

Comment: @Paparazzi all done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on newer version SQL Server (this question is tagged with sql-server-2016), then you can use the `MERGE` statement.

Here is a somewhat simplified example based on your post:

```
--create test tables
CREATE TABLE #a (UserID int);
CREATE TABLE #b (UserID int, ServiceID int);
CREATE TABLE #c (UserID int, ServiceID int, Scheduled int);

--insert some data matching the question
INSERT INTO #a
VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

INSERT INTO #b
VALUES (1, 33), (2, 44), (3, 55)

INSERT INTO #c
VALUES(2, 44, 3), (4, 66, 1)

--ensure we have data
SELECT * FROM #a
SELECT * FROM #b
SELECT * FROM #c

--use the MERGE statement
MERGE #c AS tgt
USING(SELECT a.UserID, b.ServiceID FROM #a a JOIN #b b ON a.UserID = b.UserID) src
ON (tgt.UserID = src.UserID AND tgt.ServiceID = src.ServiceID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (UserID, ServiceID, Scheduled)
  VALUES(src.UserID, src.ServiceID, 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE 
    SET Scheduled += 1;

--check what's been inserted/updated
SELECT * FROM #c
```

Be aware that `MERGE` sometimes gave performance implications, so use it with caution. More info about `MERGE` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice example but I think splitting into two statements is a better approach here.

Comment: @Niels Berglund, Thank you for this example! I had looked into using MERGE in the past, my only concern with this is that i'm going to execute this query everytime a bit field is switched to true for a particular `EVENTID` and would like to update/insert data dependant on only the records that that `EventID` is directly related too. It seems using `merge` is going to just match data from two tables without evaluating particular records only being theres not `where` statement. Could that be modified to include an event ID and trigger only data matching certain parameters for a given eventID?

Comment: Hi, Sure - you can have a `WHERE` clause in the `USING` part as well as in the `WHEN NOT MATCHED`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by executing different statements for inserting and updating.

```
-- INSERT INTO Temporary Table
SELECT  sa.UserID, 
        ce.ServiceID 
INTO    #tempC
FROM    TableA a
        JOIN TableB b ON b.EventID = a.EventID
WHERE   a.EventID = 1892286
        AND a.Attendance IN (1,2)

-- UPDATE Existing ROWS
UPDATE  c
SET     c.Scheduled = c.Scheduled + 1
FROM    #tempC c
        INNER JOIN TableC d
            ON c.UserID = d.UserID
                AND c.ServiceID = d.ServiceID

-- INSERT new rows
INSERT INTO TableC (UserID, ServiceID,Scheduled)
SELECT  c.UserID, c.ServiceID, 1
FROM    #tempC c
        LEFT JOIN TableC d
            ON c.UserID = d.UserID
                AND c.ServiceID = d.ServiceID
WHERE   d.UserID IS NULL

-- DROP temporary table
DROP TABLE #tempC
```

Comment: how do we differ from updating vs inserting in this example? I see it's doing both in this case.

Comment: they differ in the type of join used. the first uses `INNER JOIN` which will get existing record while the second one uses `LEFT JOIN` to get non existing rows.

Answer (score 1):

A loop is not efficient

`ca` and `ce` are not valid alias so I had to guess the valid alias

Start with a backup in case you do it wrong.

```
update c 
   set c.serviceID = c.serviceID + 1  
  FROM TableA a
  JOIN TableB b
    ON b.EventID = a.EventID
   and a.EventID = 1892286
   AND a.Attendance IN (1,2) 
  join TableC c 
    on c.UserID = a.UserID 
   and c.ServiceID = b.ServiceID; 

INSERT INTO TableC (UserID, ServiceID, Scheduled)
SELECT a.UserID, b.ServiceID, 1 
  FROM TableA a
  JOIN TableB b
    ON b.EventID = a.EventID
   and a.EventID = 1892286
   AND a.Attendance IN (1,2)  
 where not exists (select 1 
                     from TableC c 
                    where c.UserID = a.UserID 
                      and c.ServiceID = b.ServiceID 
                  );
```